# What to add to SELECT to output 10 RANDOM entries QUICKLY?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to make

```
SELECT w1.wort AS column1,
       w2.wort AS column2,
       w3.wort AS column3
FROM woerter AS w1,
     woerter AS w2,
     woerter AS w3
WHERE w1.wort LIKE 'a%'
  AND w2.wort LIKE 'm%'
  AND w3.wort LIKE 'o%'
```

output 10 **random** entries **quickly**?

Comment: If you want it to be quick, then don't do Cartesian products! :-)

Comment: @Rudie `quickly` means `order by random()` is to be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want quick, then `order by random()` isn't going to be fast.  Perhaps this will speed things up:

```
SELECT w1.wort AS column1,
       w2.wort AS column2,
       w3.wort AS column3
FROM (select w1.* from woerter w1 where w1.wort LIKE 'a%' order by random() limit 10) w1 cross join
     (select w2.* from woerter w2 where w2.wort LIKE 'm%' order by random() limit 10) w2 cross join
     (select w3.* from woerter w3 where w3.wort LIKE 'o%' order by random() limit 10) w3
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 10;
```

This limits the final `order by` to no more than 1000 rows and prevents an `order by` on a full cartesian product.

---

Comment: Looks good. You have a typo, though: instead of `select w1.* form` write `select w1.* from` and I can check your reply.

Comment: "order by random() is to be avoided", but here are 4... =)

Comment: @Rudie . . .That is not my quote.  Four `order by random()` on smaller sets of data is going to be much, much, much faster than almost any `order by` on a cartesian product.

Comment: I know, I was quoting OP.

Comment: @Rudie See Gordon Linoff's reply for that, he is right.

Comment: I think he's right too, I just think it's beautiful `random()` should be avoided, and now there are 4 instead of 1. If you don't think that's funny, I might have a different sense of 'humor'.